# Discord check if mentioend channel exists

Tags: discord.js

How can i check in discord.js if the used string is a channel on my discord?
discord app output: #channel,
console output: <#732610022386827404>

```
if(msgchannel == a_exisiting_channel){
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `message.mentions.channels.first()`